# The div width is not wrapping the line-break text

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tag">
    TestTestTestTest TestTestTestTestTestTest TestTestTest
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 250px
}

.tag {
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 12px;

  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see there is some space after the first line,
How to set the width of div fit the content ?
The current width should be the width of `break-all` not `break-word`

Current

```
[Test Test Test    ]
[Test              ]
```

Expected

```
[Text Text Text]  // Keep Break word and the width fit the content
[Text          ]
```

Here is the jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/1f9atmwu/

Comment: its because of `max-width: 250px`

Comment: you cannot do this

Answer (score -2):

i think also you can use flex box and use flex-wrap

Comment: Can you give me the example ? Thanks